# Can't install Sierra on triple boot MacBook Pro with rEFInd

Tags: bootcamp, install, macos, efi

I have downloaded Sierra from App Store and tried to install but I am not able to select a disk. I have installed [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) on my MacBook Pro and have triple boot (Mac OS X, Windows 10 and Ubuntu). How can I install it?

My Mac info:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) - El Capitan

[image: macOS Installer - Select Disk]

After several reboots I was not able to see `rEFInd` menu. So I have tried to reinstall. Here is the reinstall output:

```
ShimSource is none
Installing rEFInd on OS X....
Warning: root device could not be found
Installing rEFInd to the partition mounted at /Volumes/ESP
Found rEFInd installation in /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind; upgrading it.
Found suspected Linux partition(s); installing ext4fs driver.
Installing driver for ext4 (ext4_x64.efi)
Copied rEFInd binary files

Notice: Backed up existing icons directory as icons-backup.
Existing refind.conf file found; copying sample file as refind.conf-sample
to avoid overwriting your customizations.


Installation has completed successfully.
```

Here is `sudo gpt -r show disk0` output:

```
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  469394016      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  469803656    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  471073192  195312500      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  666385692        740         
  666386432   17643520      7  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  684029952  292151296      5  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  976181248     921600      6  GPT part - DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
  977102848       2179         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

And here is `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` output:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   1 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
*2: DA 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  469394016] <Unknown ID>
 3: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 469803656 -    1269536] HFS+        
 4: 83 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 471073192 -  195312500] Linux files*
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I wasn't able to change my partitions using `Disk Utility`. I have used `Paragon Disk Manager for Mac` and deleted my linux partitions, main and swap.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have also deleted my bootcamp partition. My current partition data is as following:

Output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0`:

```
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  469394016      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  469803656       3448         
  469807104    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  471076640  506028387         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

Output of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 -   25 127  14 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
*2: DA   25 127  15 - 1023 235  56 [    409640 -  469394016] <Unknown ID>
 3: AF 1023  35  40 - 1023  41  62 [ 469807104 -    1269536] HFS+        
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

I am still not able to slect disk to install.

**UPDATE**

I have realized that `FireVault` is enabled. I have disabled it and managed to install `Sierra`.

Comment: I have both tried with USB thumb and installer from App Store and same result with one difference: When I first tried with USB I have managed to select the drive Macintosh HD but installer asked password for unlocking the drive. I have entered my account password but encountered same screen that I shared.

Comment: Perhaps I shuld do something with rEFInd.

Comment: @klanomath I have eadded.

Comment: I think you meant "FileVault" not "FireVault." If disabling FileVault turned out to be the solution, you should add it as an "Answer" to your question. But, was this after you nuked all of your partitions? Do you know if there's a chance to preserve all of the other OSes?

Answer (score -1):

It's because ReIfind doesn't work with Sierra

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions